# Segmentation fault cmovl

Tags: linux, assembly

I get the error 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' when trying to run some compiled assembly. The code that makes the program crash is the following:

```
.global tiny
.type tiny, @function
tiny:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    subl $16, %esp
    # Compiling A1MINUS
    movl $3, %eax
    negl %eax
    movl %eax, -4(%ebp)
    # Compiling A0
    movl -4(%ebp), %eax
    movl %eax, -8(%ebp)
    # Compiling A0
    movl $7, %eax
    movl %eax, -12(%ebp)
    movl -8(%ebp), %eax
    cmp %eax, -12(%ebp) // Error
    movl $1, %eax // Error
    movl %eax, %ebx //Error
    movl $0, %eax //Error
    cmovl %eax, %ebx // Error
    movl %eax, -16(%ebp) // Error
    # IF
    movl -16(%ebp), %eax 
    cmp %eax , 0 
    jz lbl_3
    movl -8(%ebp), %eax
    pushl %eax
    call print_int
    addl $4, %esp
jmp lbl_4
lbl_3:
    movl -12(%ebp), %eax
    pushl %eax
    call print_int
    addl $4, %esp
lbl_4:
    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

I have no clue what my mistake is, any help is appreciated.

The wrong code (**cmovl**) is supposed to place a 0 or 1 in **-16(%ebp)**, depending on the result of the comparison done by **cmp**. (the broken code is a translation of a 'lower then' statement).

As said in the comments, cmovl appearently can't make the code crash. Now I am even more clueless.

Comment: `cmovl` can't make code crash because it only operates on registers, except on processors that don't support it. Of course it might have some effect that makes other part of the code crash. Have you used a debugger so you are sure the fault is at that place?

Comment: @Jester, thanks for the reply. I don't really know how to debug assembly. The code crashes since I added the 6 marked lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure the line `cmp %eax, 0` causes the crash, because in at&t syntax the `0` there is a memory reference, a `NULL` pointer. Presumably you wanted to compare eax to 0, in which case you need `cmp $0, %eax`.

Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: This fixed it. I forgot the dollar sign .. Sigh